# Returning a row when the row doesn't exist in an Oracle table, using IN condition

Tags: oracle, row, conditional-statements

I have an Oracle query like this:

```
select col1, col2
from table
where col1 in (111, 222, 333);
```

Let's say that 111 and 333 exist, but 222 doesn't. I want to get 3 rows back, including one for 222, even though that value doesn't exist in the table.  Like this, for example:

```
col1 col2
---- ----
 111 aaa
 222 NoValue
 333 ccc
```

Of course I get just 2 rows back. How do I get a row back for every value in the in condition, even when the row doesn't exist in the table?

I was doing individual queries for every value of col1, getting back either 0 or 1 row, but that gets inefficient when there are many rows involved, which is why I want to do this in one query.

To summarize, I need to know, for every value in the in condition, (1) if a row exists (and what the value of col2 is), or (2) if the row doesn't exist.  I found ways to do something similar, but not with an in condition.  That's the part that has me stumped.  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Where are the values in the IN list coming from?  You'd need to get them in some sort of collection/ global temporary table/ CTE and left join from that to your table.  If those values are coming from another query, life is trivial.  If you're getting the elements from somewhere else but you have the ability to transform them into a CTE that does a series of selects from dual, that works but it's going to potentially generate a bunch of non-sharable SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a row source for the list of values you want to check against.  Then, `LEFT JOIN` your table to that row source.  Like this:

```
WITH t AS
       (SELECT 111 col1,
               'aaa' col2
        FROM   DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 333,
               'ccc'
        FROM   DUAL),
     check_list AS
       (SELECT 111 check_value FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 222 FROM DUAL
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 333 FROM DUAL)
SELECT check_list.check_value col1,
       t.col2
FROM   check_list LEFT JOIN t ON t.col1 = check_list.check_value
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an outer join against a subquery. The subquery is simply a list of values converted to a collection, which can be evaluated as a table:

```
select b.col1, col2 
from  a
right join (
    select column_value as col1 
    from table(sys.odcinumberlist(111,222,333))
) b 
on a.col1 = b.col1
;
```